# mediaelement.js - Play random video?

Tags: wordpress, mediaelement.js, shortcode

I have lots of videos in the directory "video" in my WordPress installation.

They all play nice using the [MediaElement.js](http://www.mediaelementjs.com/) plugin, but is it also possible to play a random clip from this directory? For example using a shortcode that directs to the directory (and not to a specific video), something like

```
[video src="http://www.domain.com/wordpress/wp-content/video" random="true"]
```

That would be great!

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible.

What you might want to do is use AJAX to generate the div containing your video player. If you do this, you can delete/recreate the player very easily.

After that what you'd need is a shortcode definition which feeds a directory string value and a boolean value into whichever function you attach to the shortcode handler.

**For Instance**

> $defaultDirectory=[site_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_urlhttp://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url)+"/videos/";

```
add_shortcode( 'video', 'videoDiv' );

function videoDiv( $shortcodeAttributeList )
{
  extract( shortcode_atts( array(
             'src'    => $defaultDirectory,
             'random' => true,              /*set default values, use lowercase*/
         ), $shortcodeAttributeList ) );

  if($random)
  {
      $numFiles=fileCounter($src);
      $choice=rand(1, $numFiles);
  }

  $output='<div id="videoPlayer" class="player">';
  // Continue by making a string which spans from <div> to </div>

  return $output; //a div
}
```

Also from http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

```
<?php
/**
* get the number of files within a given dir
*/
function fileCounter($dir){
    $counter = 0;
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
      //echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
      //echo "Files:\n";
      /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
      while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
          //echo "<BR>".$counter." - $file";
          $counter++;
      }
      closedir($handle);
    }
    $counter -= 1; // in order to exclude '.' and '..', as well as start the counter on 1
    return $counter;
}
/**
* get the filename in a giver dir, starting the first file with the index 1
*/
function fileNameByIndex($dir, $fileIndex){
    $counter = 0;
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
      while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
          $counter++;
          if($counter - 2 == $fileIndex)
              return $file;
      }
      closedir($handle);
    }
    return "";
}
}
```